# How create model objects when one of field foreign key without value

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `League`

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country_code = models.ForeignKey("Country",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    season = models.ForeignKey('Season',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    season_start = models.DateField(null = True)
    season_end = models.DateField(null = True)
    league_logo = models.URLField(null = True)      league_flag = models.URLField(null = True)
    standings = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

One of the fields `country_code` related with foreign key to another field which at time of creating object from model league will be without any value without data. What is right way of creating objects from models when foreign keys of this model reference to tables without data

Comment: Did you try to set `country_code` to `None` when creating the model instance?

Comment: since you have set `null=True` for country_code, it will accept empty values.

Comment: I wasnt know that if i specify null=True that field can ignore foreign keybwithout value. I will try to do. Thanks

Comment: No. Didn't try. I thought that should be the right way without changing field value

Comment: you can add `default=None` to `country_code` . by this way not need to set it to `None` during creating `League` instance and it will be `None` itself.